# Restlet-1.1 example\book\rest\ch2\Example2_5 no client connectors for HTTPS

Tags: java, https, jetty, restlet

Example2_5 creates a client for HTTPS to handle request

```
final Response response = new Client(Protocol.HTTPS).handle(request);
```

The only related jar in Restlet-1.1 is `org.mortbay.jetty.https.jar`, which I added to my runtime classpath.

Nevertheless, I am getting at runtime

```
[java] WARNING: No available client connector supports the required protoco
ls: 'HTTPS' . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath.
```

Although it's a warning, it leads to null as a return on

```
final DomRepresentation document = response.getEntityAsDom();
```

Was anyone able to run any of Examples in Restlet-1.1 that are restlets equivalents of Ruby's example from "RESTful Web Services" book?

Vitaly

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the Restlet connectors web page](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/connectors), there is no Jetty client connector for HTTPS.

I was able to get better results with the "Net" connector (based on the `java.net` classes), which required me to add the `com.noelios.restlet.ext.net.jar` file to my classpath.

Apparently the Apache Commons HTTP Client is also supported for HTTPS.